# Show match array data between database and array

Tags: php, arrays, database, api

I have a problem. 
This data on my database table of column name `"XYZ"`

```
string 'aaa' (length=3)
string 'bbb' (length=3)
string 'ccc' (length=3)
```

and this is api array (fetch data). Now I want which `"property_name"` match in my database column `"XYZ"` show only this array. How can I do that?

```
array (size=12)
  'property_code' => string 'YXDUB006' (length=8)
  'property_name' => string 'bbb' (length=19)
  'address' => 
    array (size=4)
      'line1' => string 'Jessop Street' (length=13)
      'city' => string 'County Laois' (length=12)
      'postal_code' => string 'R32 RV20' (length=8)
      'country' => string 'IE' (length=2)
  'contacts' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'PHONE' (length=5)
          'detail' => string '353-578-678588' (length=14)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'FAX' (length=3)
          'detail' => string '353-57-8678577' (length=14)


  array (size=13)
  'property_code' => string 'YXDUB006' (length=8)
  'property_name' => string 'aaa' (length=19)
  'address' => 
    array (size=4)
      'line1' => string 'Jessop Street' (length=13)
      'city' => string 'County Laois' (length=12)
      'postal_code' => string 'R32 RV20' (length=8)
      'country' => string 'IE' (length=2)
  'contacts' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'PHONE' (length=5)
          'detail' => string '353-578-678588' (length=14)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'FAX' (length=3)
          'detail' => string '353-57-8678577' (length=14)


 array (size=14)
  'property_code' => string 'YXDUB006' (length=8)
  'property_name' => string 'ggg' (length=19)
  'address' => 
    array (size=4)
      'line1' => string 'Jessop Street' (length=13)
      'city' => string 'County Laois' (length=12)
      'postal_code' => string 'R32 RV20' (length=8)
      'country' => string 'IE' (length=2)
  'contacts' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'PHONE' (length=5)
          'detail' => string '353-578-678588' (length=14)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'FAX' (length=3)
          'detail' => string '353-57-8678577' (length=14)
```

Comment: Did you take a look at how to manipulate arrays? Anything you tried already? The idea is to supply code that doesn't work. Right now you are only describing a problem, supplying data

Comment: @AlivetoDie looks like a few loops too many to me

Comment: No need for two foreach loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array(); 
$sql="select hotel FROM hotels"; 
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    foreach($api_array as &$value){ 
        if($myrow['hotel'] == $value['property_name']){ 
            $final_array[] = $value; 
        } 
    } 
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```